# Which scale value to use with Landsat 8 Band 10 when calculating Top of atmosphere Radiance

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8

I'm trying to calculate LST over a large area using Landsat 8 Band 10 and the attached method.

I've determined that the DN value for band 10 isn't right and is the cause of incorrect (nonsense) values calculated for LST.

I've looked on here, and at several sources including the Landsat documentation but have just become more confused.

Per the attached formula (peer reviewed, and known to work), the Top of Atmosphere Radiance is: the band-specific multiplicative rescaling factor from the image metadata x DN value for Band 10 + band specific additive rescaling factor from the image metadata.

For example, this gives: `3.342x10^-4 x 3271 + 0.1` for a Band 10 DN value of 3271.

On this page - https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C01_T1_SR - the scale factor for Band 10 is given as 0.1.  If I multiply the Band 10 value by 10 I get a sensible result, but I don't understand the process, or the meaning of the two scale factors.

Why is one specific to each image, and the other consistent across all data?

Referring to the example above, should my actual calculation be 3.342x10^-4 x (3271 * 10) + 0.1 for a Band 10 DN value of 3271?  Why?

I'm working in Earth Engine as the process will need to be automated and scaled in due course.

In the meantime I shall continue reading.

[image]

Comment: What Landsat collection are you using? Are you using Collection 1 Tier 1 images ( https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C01_T1_SR )? If so, note that band 10 has already been covnerted to TOA brightness temperatures, e.g. a pixel value of 3271 represents 327.1 Kelvin multiplied by 10

Comment: Thanks -@korndog - that's handy to know.  I'm using Collection 2 Tier 1.  I've spent hours and hours looking for the info I need to understand this and can't find it.   Bands 1-7 have a scale factor of 0.0001, and bands 10 and 11 a scale factor of 0.1.  I cannot find ANYWHERE what the scale factor is for - what it does.  Is it to make processing more efficient?  Is it inherent in the sensor (in which case, why not include it in the processing?)  I'm pretty sure I can make my data work now - by multiplying the Band 10 value by 10 - (0.1 x 10 = 1), but I need to know why!!!

Comment: I still need to know how to calculate Top of Atmosphere Radiance, and then ToA Brightness Temperature.  :)  Just so confused now.  :(

Comment: Thanks for your reply @strangecharm. It doesn't seem like Collection 2 images are on the GEE data catalogue. To confirm once more, you are using the following image colection: `LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR`? If yes--- B10 pixel values are brightness temperatures (scaled by a factor of 10). The scale factors of are used for data storage purposes, e.g. a reflectance is defined on [0,1].. to store as a 16bit integer while keeping the same precision, they're scaled by 10000; brightness temperatures are scaled by 10 to conserve precision of a 10th of a Kelvin.

Comment: The workflow you shared uses raw TM/OLI images which you can access from the image colleciton `LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1`. The pixel values here contain digital numbers and you can apply the workflow directly. You will notice that the brightness temperatures you calculate from the raw images will be equivalent to what's given in B10 of the collection `LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR` up to a 10th of a Kelvin

Comment: Thanks @korndog, and oops.  This is a handy workflow lesson.  I found an appropriate single image (to make a start) using earthexplorer.usgs.gov, and I'm sure that was Collection 2.  I modified the filename and successfully mapped the scene in GEE...but in the process didn't notice the C01 in the path. Thanks especially for explaining the use of scale - I'm not sure I quite understand it yet (intuitively, at least, still very new to coding), but it's all the pointer I need to work it out.  :)  I shall get some sleep and come back to this.  o7